# C# - Replacing "." to "," in double value

Tags: c#, localization, double, number-formatting, decimal-point

I have to read a .txt and display it. The double values in the data are written with a ".". When I have german language enabled it doesn't interpret it as a comma. Now I tried to check if the language is set to German and replace all the "." with a ",". The values are stored in an array named "_value" but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
 if ((System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName) == "de")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _value.Length; i++)
                {
                    String temp_var = Convert.ToString(_value[i]);
                    temp_var.Replace(".", ",");
                    _value[i] = Convert.ToDouble(temp_var);
                }
            }
```

Comment: can i get more information? where did it failed? what do u see in the watches?

Comment: `double`s don't *have* any separator in them - whatever you do to a *string* will not be respected if you turn them back into `double`s. You might want to read up on [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) to understand what is actually *stored* in a `double` variable.

Comment: I see anything. It shows me the wrong number again. I just need to change the "." into "," and store it back into the array but arrays seperate the values with "," so what should I do?

Comment: solved the problem! :)

Comment: .Replace does not modify the value of the current instance. It returns a new string with the modifications. So you need to consume the returned value in another string or in the same instance.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking the language, you can also supply the culture with which the conversion is done:

```
// Convert string to double from the invariant culture, which treats "." as decimal:
double d = Convert.ToDouble(_value[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Convert double to string using the current culture, which may happen to be German and uses a ",":
string s = Convert.ToString(d);

// Or convert double to string using the specific German culture:
string s = Convert.ToString(d, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

What I don't understand is that apparently the `_value` array is already a `double[]` - so these changes will have to be made *earlier* in your code, where the conversion from string to double actually happens.

Comment: How does that look in the code? When my Array looks like [12.34,13.45] the numbers should look like 12,34 but in an array thats not possible or am I wrong?

Comment: @uzi42tmp I changed my answer to convert back to string as well.

Comment: How do i store the values back to an array without causing errors?

Comment: Worked when I added the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to the line where he stores the values into the array! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you don't just [set the appropriate culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(v=vs.110).aspx) temporarily?

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Yes. It shall depend on where you start the programm.

Comment: @uzi42tmp So sometimes there's indeed a dot as a separator?